# MAX Value from SQL to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, max

How do I retrieve the max value of a column in SQL using PHP?

Table name is `pages`.

The code I have written into a function is:

```
function max_from_page($column) {
        global $db;
        $sql = "SELECT MAX('" . $column . "')";
        $sql.= "FROM pages";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        return $result;
    }
```

UPDATE 1:
I added an alias:

```
function max_from_page($column) {
        global $db;
        $sql = "SELECT MAX(" . $column . ") AS maxsub";
        $sql.= "FROM pages";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        return $result;
    }
```

Then a var dump echo'ed `bool(false)`

UPDATE 2:
So after adding a space before `FROM`
The var dump gives me this:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

The max value I am expecting returned is `3`.
The above code executes absolutely fine on MYSQL command line.

Comment: Give the result of MAX() an alias and then refer to it like you would any column identifier

Comment: @JohnConde I am a beginner. I tried using 'AS' but how do I return this alias?

Comment: Probably need a space before FROM.

Comment: @AbraCadaver good spot. but still no success. Now the var_dump says that it's returning an object. check out my update above.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/),  or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Where in the code are you doing the var_dump?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld all functions are in one file which is included in 2nd file. I am calling var dump in this second file.

$temp = max_from_page("subject_id");
echo var_dump($temp);

Comment: And now you want to fetch.  Look at the mysqli functions for examples.

Comment: Try to do var_dump($result) inside of the function max_from_page before returning $result. Do you get the expected result then?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Just tried that. Output doesn't change. It is exactly as I stated above in my question(UPDATE2).

Comment: aha. I've provided an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);` to return the result. `mysqli_query` does return an `mysqli-object` (if query has been sucsseful) but wont return the actual result of the query.

**You should use**

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

And then you would have `$result['maxsub']` as the value you're looking for.

Comment: I think we are moving in the right direction. I did try fetch assoc but it gives me an error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /Users/amarjeet/Sites/globe_bank/private/query_functions.php on line 195
21121

Comment: You will have to execute the query first and then do the mysqli_fetch_assoc. Look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php for examples.

Comment: So I had $column back in single quotes just as I was trying out different options along with fetch assoc. Once I removed the single quotes it worked!!! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help! Thank you!